# Print something when a word is in a word list

Tags: python

So I am currently trying to build a Caesar encrypted that automatically tries all the possibilities and compares them to a big list of words to see if it is a real word, so some sort of dictionary attack I guess.
I found a list with a lot of German words, and they even are split so that each word is on a new line. Currently, I am struggling with comparing the sentence that I currently have with the whole word list. So that when the program sees that a word in my sentence is also a word in the Word list that it prints out that this is a real word and possible the right sentence.
So this is how far I currently am, I have not included the code with which I try all the 26 letters. Only my way to look through the word list and compares it to a sentence. Maybe someone can tell me what I am doing wrong and why it doesn't work:

No idea why it doesn't work. I have also tried it with regular expressions but nothing works. The list is really long (166k Words).

Comment: Are you aware that `"Hello there".capitalize()` results in the same string, `"Hello there"`? Did you mean to convert it to upper case?

Comment: Yes I am aware of that all I wanted to do is to capitalize the first word because I only compare the first word later anyway

Comment: Why did you remove your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are `/n` at the en of each word of the list you created from the file, so the they will never be the same as what they are compared to.

Remove the newline character before appending (you can, for example, `wordlist.append(line.rstrip())`